# How do I use Javascript in my address bar to scroll vertically by a specific number of pixels?

Tags: javascript

I am on a web page. It is not a web page I am making, but a web page I am browsing. I want to be able to scroll by a specific number of pixels by typing into my address bar in chrome. I want a general solution that could be applied to other web pages as well, assuming I access the correct element with the scroll bar. I want to be able to do this in my address bar preferably. In a way that is easily repeatable.

I have tried

```
javascript:$(window).scrollBy(0, 100);

javascript:$(window).scrollTo(0, 100);
```

to no avail. I do not know much javascript but I am guessing there is a more formal way to access the page element with the scroll bar, that I am as yet unaware of.

Comment: You need to use your developer tools and use the console.

Comment: If you're using chrome, develope an extension that will do it for you.

Comment: Your code assumes that the page has jQuery. If it doesn't, then the code won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the jQuery selector for the window.

Try

```
javascript:window.scrollTo(0, 100);void(0);
```

When dealing with frames, I've found I need to select the frame first.

```
var myframe = document.getElementsByName('myframename')[0];
myframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0,100);
```

Note: I've used the above for grabbing elements in frame. I don't know if it will work for your use case.

Previous usage:

```
document.getElementsByName('myframename')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByName('mybuttonname')[1].click();
```

Comment: I have found that this works for most pages, however there are a few pages with unconventional frames that don't seem to work. I try getting the ID with document.getElementById("name_str").scrollBy(x,y), but I get an error in the console window.

Comment: You'll need to chase the error. I'll add a few things I've learned to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First off, stop using JQuery. If you want it to work anywhere, you'll need to work with the raw DOM.

To scroll down 100 pixels, type:

```
javascript:void(window.scrollBy(0, 100));
```

To scroll to 100 pixels down, type:

```
javascript:void(window.scrollTo(0, 100));
```